# Trying to help someone get back into the USA

Tags: usa, payment-cards, scams

If they are needing to get back into USA is an eBay card actually helping them or is it a scam

Comment: Probably a scam. Any request for money to travel should be presumed to be a scam until you talk (not e-mail, actually talk) with the person.

Comment: The person is coming back Poland said they only accept eBay cards as pay

Comment: Is this someone personally known to you, such as a close relative or friend, trusted by you, and have you talked with them? (It is harder to impersonate someone over the phone or skype than in e-mail or text messages).

Comment: Poland has several Western Union locations, where the person could get Polish cash, if they really were in Poland. An eBay card can be used from anywhere in the world, once one has the redemption code that can be e-mailed.

Comment: Just meet him on line and he lived in Pennsylvania but had to travel to Poland for work.

Comment: You mean he _said_ he lived in Pennsylvania. This reeks of scam.

Comment: Don't send this man money, and certainly not on an eBay card. If you really think he needs help, offer to buy his flight from Poland to USA and see how quickly he loses interest.

Comment: @DavidSupportsMonica makes an important point. You seem to be thinking of things you saw in on-line communications as facts, as though you know he, she, or they lived in Pennsylvania and traveled to Poland. All you really know is that you saw some words in on-line communications.

Comment: Can anything happen if I did

Comment: You would lose your money. And probably the person would think you gullible and try to scam you for even more money with a new story. There is actually no part of the US visa or entry process that requires eBay cards.

Comment: In addition to losing any money you send, watch out for attempts to get information that would be useful for identity theft (legal name, place and date of birth, parents' names, including mother's maiden name).

Comment: Yeah already tried to get bank information and told him no and he said just send the eBay card number

Comment: Good for you on not giving out bank information. (If you had, I would be advising you to get off the computer and call the bank's security number NOW).

Comment: Yeah thanks so much I just told him I would buy his plane ticket

Comment: To my mind, the attempt to get bank information removes the last remaining sliver of a possibility that it is not a scam.

Comment: What do you mean sorry

Comment: She means that the other party's attempt to get your bank information _confirms_ this is a scam. I agree.